# How to stop execution in jConfirm condition in jquery-alerts.js

Tags: jquery, jconfirm

Please check the following code:

I don't want to execute `alert('End');` before confirming the confirmation dialog.

```html
<link href="http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/jquery.alerts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready( function() {
            $("#confirm_button").click( function() {
     alert('Start');
                    jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
                 if(r){alert('Ok');}else{alert('Cancel');}
             });
      alert('End');
    });
});

  </script>
<fieldset>
   <legend>Confirm</legend>
 
   <p>
    <input id="confirm_button" type="button" value="Show Confirm">
   </p>
  </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop the code from executing, when you're calling async functions (like jConfirm in this case, another popuplar example is `ajax()`).

When you're working with async functions, you must also work with callback functions.

Code that needs to be executed after the dialog is closed needs to go into `function(r) { ... }` - everything else will be executed parallel.

```
jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
    if(r){alert('Ok');}else{alert('Cancel');}
    // Put your code here and it will be executed when the dialog is closed.
});
```

```html
<link href="http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/jquery.alerts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready( function() {
            $("#confirm_button").click( function() {
     alert('Start');
                    jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
                 if(r){alert('Ok');}else{alert('Cancel');}
                    alert('End');
             });
      
    });
});

  </script>
<fieldset>
   <legend>Confirm</legend>
 
   <p>
    <input id="confirm_button" type="button" value="Show Confirm">
   </p>
  </fieldset>
```

Comment: Thank you Mike for your valuable comment. but have huge code which I want to call outside jConfirm function.
is there any alternate method ?

Comment: No. Put your code into functions and call the next function from within the jConfirm callback. Once you get used to working with callbacks you'll notice that it will even help you design cleaner structured code.